# Meditative-self

Tags: meditation, vipassana, tipitaka, yuttadhammo

Bhikkhu Yuttadhammo mentioned that one shouldn't build up a meditative-self while being a meditator.

How can I prevent this from happening, as I have been quite stiff and getting quieter and more serious lately. Or is that not have to do with a 'meditative-self' view?

Please help!

Answer (score 1):

He probably means that one can attatch to the process of transcending attatchment. If one is always a meditator striving towards Nirvana when  how can they get to Nirvana? One may merely believe in the meditative self because it is against the flow of what one was. The only one who is heroic in this way is ego.

Prevent the meditative self by not clinging to preventing the process as it continues.

Answer (score 0):

> How can I prevent this from happening, as I have been quite stiff and getting quieter and more serious lately. Or is that not have to do with a 'meditative-self' view?

When thoughts about a self arises just note them. They all belong to the 4th aggreagate of mental formations. There isn't really anything to do other than being mindful of them and reminding yourself.